# Firebase Web - Is it possible to get the value's name?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is there a way for me to retrieve the name of a value?
For example:
[image: data image]

I want to get the value names highlighted in yellow.

However, right now I can only get:
[image: web page image]

From my understanding the below code only return the value which is the player's scores.

```
var childData = childSnapshot.val();
```

Can I do something like this to get the value name?

```
var childValueName = childSnapshot.val().name;
```

This is my java code:

```
  function PrintData()
  {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('Score');
    var PrintData = document.getElementById('PrintOutData');

   ref.on("value", function(snapshot)
   {
     PrintData.innerText = "";
     snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot)
     {
       console.log("childSnapshot.key: " + childSnapshot.key);
       var childData = childSnapshot.val();
       let keys = Object.keys(childData)
        keys.forEach(key => {
            let value = childData[key.toString()];
            console.log("value: " + value);
            PrintData.innerText += childSnapshot.key + ": " + value +"\r";
        })
     });
   });
  }
```

My html code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="PrintData()">Print!</button>
```

Please correct me if I am wrong! Thankyou.

Comment: What do you mean by `value name`? Do you want `tag name` which contains this value?

Comment: Hi @VicJordan , what's a tag name? In my first picture above, I could only get the scores (numbers) but not the "GamePlay" names. I want to get the entire line!

Comment: Add your html code and JavaScript code as well in question

Comment: You're going to have to show your query so we can understand what exactly `childSnapshot` is.

Comment: @VicJordan hi, I just added my codes, thanks

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry, just posted my codes ~

Comment: Is that not just `key` inside your `keys.forEach`?

Answer (score 2):

See [firebase.database.DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key)

**key**
(string or null)

The key (last part of the path) of the location of this DataSnapshot.

The last token in a Database location is considered its key. For example, "ada" is the key for the /users/ada/ node. Accessing the key on any `DataSnapshot` will return the key for the location that generated it. However, accessing the key on the root URL of a Database will return `null`.

```
// Assume we have the following data in the Database:
{
  "name": {
    "first": "Ada",
    "last": "Lovelace"
  }
}

var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/ada");
ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key; // "ada"
    var childKey = snapshot.child("name/last").key; // "last"
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has a well versed and beautiful documentation.
According to [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot), datasnapshot is returned when you pass a relative path to the child() method

```
// Assume we have the following data in the Database:
{
 "name": {
 "first": "Ada",
 "last": "Lovelace"
 }
}

// Test for the existence of certain keys within a DataSnapshot
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/ada");
 ref.once("value")
.then(function(snapshot) {
  var name = snapshot.child("name").val(); // {first:"Ada",last:"Lovelace"}
  var firstName = snapshot.child("name/first").val(); // "Ada"
  var lastName = snapshot.child("name").child("last").val(); // "Lovelace"
  var age = snapshot.child("age").val(); // null
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following may work for your purpose:

```
firebase.database().ref('score').once('value', snap => {
  var data = snap.val() // should return => {User1: {GamePlay00: 3}, User2:
  {GamePlay00: 1}, ...}

  var users = Object.keys('data') should return // => [User1, User2, ...]

  var usersDatas = users.map(user_id => data[user_id]) // should return something like => [{gamePlay00: 3}, {gamePlay00:1}, ...]

  var value = usersDatas.map(game_play_id => game_play_id) // should return => [gamePlay00, gamePlay00...]
})
```

Please refer to these link for further documentation: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#get_a_database_reference)

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick to using `Snapshot.forEach()` for the lower level too:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('Score');
var PrintData = document.getElementById('PrintOutData');

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  PrintData.innerText = "";
  snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
    console.log("childSnapshot.key: " + userSnapshot.key);
    userSnapshot.forEach(function(gameSnapshot) {
      PrintData.innerText += gameSnapshot.key + ": " + gameSnapshot.val() +"\r";
    })
  });
});
```